# How do I create a demo account in Django?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have visited a couple of sites and they offer the option to try their site without registering, but you can login with something like `someusername@somesite.com` and `somesiteguest`.

I want to implement this for my own site. Currently I am using django-allauth for handling registration and logins.

I am just not sure how to handle users login with the same credentials.

Comment: Why don't you create an account(demo) with limited permissions?

Comment: @Dhruv You mean an account with different credentials for every user ?

Comment: Not for every user, only one set of credentials for each of the users who want to demo?; Do you want to be able to create multiple demo accounts?

Comment: My aim is a single set of credentials for all the users that want to just  try my site. Users can register with their email and password if they want, also.

Comment: That should be easy(if I correctly understood your use case). Have a data migration that creates a user with a specific pass/username or better have a fixture file and use that for creating a demo user. If you're looking at automating the entire process a detailed example can be seen [here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/tree/master/sandbox).

Comment: What would happen if two or more demo users tried to login with the same credentials ?

Comment: just use registeration as flag and restrict access based on registeration, if not register can see page1 but with registeration can access page 2